# SQL Server Freetext Search or other way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example I've table with some names:

```
+-------------------+
| Names             |
+-------------------+
| John Smith Doe    |
| James Black Dean  |
+-------------------+
```

I'll do a search for:

`SQL * FROM TableNames WHERE Names LIKE '%Robert Black%'`

But this will not return any results, how could I make it return the result that have Black on the Name, the only way is to use fulltext search?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to match Names that contain either 'Robert' or 'Black'? If so, use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableNames
WHERE Names LIKE '%Robert%'
    OR Names LIKE '%Black%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a row which has `Black` you should query like this
`SQL * FROM TableNames WHERE Names LIKE '%Black%'`